# How to get both value and text from select in vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Html:

```
<select v-model="facilitySelected" name="facilities" multiple="multiple" id="facilities" size="4" class="form-control">
  <option value="1">Double (Non a/c)</option>
  <option value="2">Premium Double (a/c)</option>
  <option value="3">Standard Double (a/c)</option>
</select>
```

Click event:

```
<a @click="addFacilities" class="btn btn-default add_option" rel="facilities2" id="add"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
```

Script:

```
export default {
  data(){
            return{
                facilitySelected:[]
            }
  }

  methods: {
      addFacilities() {
        this.facilitySelected;
        console.log(this.facilitySelected);
      }
  }
}
```

Here i have a list of select with options,
When i click on the `addFacilities`, the `value` of the selected option only making as output in `console.log`, i need to have both `value` as well as the `text` in the option to be come out through console.log.. How to get both the `value` and the `text` when i click on the `addFacilities`?

Answer (score 6):

In Vue, your `value` can be a complex object.

In this example, the values are an object holding both the text and the value. When they are selected, you can see you have both available in `facilitySelected`.

```js
console.clear()


new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    facilitySelected: []
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="facilitySelected" name="facilities" multiple="multiple" id="facilities" size="4" class="form-control">
  <option :value="{value: 1, text:'Double (Non a/c)'}">Double (Non a/c)</option>
  <option :value="{value: 2, text:'Premium Double (a/c)'}">Premium Double (a/c)</option>
  <option :value="{value: 3, text:'Standard Double (a/c)'}">Standard Double (a/c)</option>
</select>
  <hr> Selected: {{facilitySelected}}
</div>
```

But you can make this easier and avoid repeating yourself by storing your options in data.

```js
console.clear()


new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    facilitySelected: [],
    options: [{
        value: 1,
        text: 'Double (Non a/c)'
      },
      {
        value: 2,
        text: 'Premium Double (a/c)'
      },
      {
        value: 3,
        text: 'Standard Double (a/c)'
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="facilitySelected" name="facilities" multiple="multiple" id="facilities" size="4" class="form-control">
  <option v-for="option in options" :value="option">{{option.text}}</option>
</select>
  <hr> Selected: {{facilitySelected}}
</div>
```